# node.js and json runtime error

Tags: json, node.js

I am using node.js and trying to parse the JSON body of a request.
I am getting the following error:

```
undefined:0

^
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\node\xxxx.js:36:14)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:64:17)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnMessageComplete [as onMessageComplete] (http.js:130:23)
    at Socket.ondata (http.js:1506:22)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:374:27)
```

I am doing:

```
     request.on('data', function(chunk)
    {
    data+=chunk;
    });
     // and in the end I am doing
     obj = JSON.parse(data);  // it's complaining at this point.
```

input is:

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "source": "chat"
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "in the end I am doing"? As Joe said, this needs to be done in the 'done' event so that it happens after the request body has been fully assembled, but it's not clear from your OP whether you're doing this.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You're trying to parse the data before it is completely recieved...put your JSON.parse inside the .end method of request

```
var data = '';
request.on('data', function(chunk){
  data += chunk;
});
request.on('end', function(){
  var obj = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. even that check di dnot help

Comment: a try/catch would stop it from throwing an exception...IS the object already parsed or is JSON.parse having a problem with the string?

Comment: Its the JSON.parser is having problem. As I pasted in the question. it is a valid Json body with each element in "".

Comment: What you pasted is how an object outputs...valid JSON is a string ```'{"result": "success", "source": "chat"}'```

Comment: I'd recommend in the catch block logging/outputting the bad data so you can see what's going on.  As currently written you'd swallow the error silently, which usually leads to trouble later.

Comment: @joe I used try/catch as you suggested. my issue is I am not able to get why I am getting this Error. I think we need to fix that

Comment: @pastor Bones,  Actually I posted you the input I am sending using a REST API client. all I am trying to do is to parser it.

Comment: I tried and have the same code..really not getting why I am getting the exception

Comment: your data source is not returning valid json

Comment: As I posted I am sending the same json and verified that it is correct  one from jsonlint

Comment: yes you are right. when I hard corded the value of data as '{"result": "success", "source": "chat"}'. it works. how to get resolve this issue because I want to get it working from the user input parameters,,,,I am using RESTclient from firefox

Comment: if it's being url encoded during transmission, simply url decode it using [decodeuricomponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp) befor trying to parse it with ```JSON.parse()```

Comment: You are calling JSON.Parse before you get data in .on('data').  You should put in some logging to see what data you have, when.

Comment: weird... I am getting the error even in 'end': and data is empty, even though I am assigning it to a request property and it shows up in that property later

Comment: Also be careful, parsing the json in `request.on('data', ...` might work, I was doing this and all was fine until the size of the json being parsed grew sufficiently that it was sent in multiple chunks, and then this error occurred.

Answer (score 3):

With your edit: where in your code are you doing JSON.parse? Remember that request.on is async; you can't call `JSON.parse` until the data is done (`request.on('end')`)... if you're just calling it next, then you're likely calling it before the data has arrived.

E.g.

```
request.on('data', function(chunk)
    {
    data+=chunk;
    });

request.on('end', function() {
     obj = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

would work, but

```
request.on('data', function(chunk)
    {
    data+=chunk;
    });

obj = JSON.parse(data);
```

will not, because the JSON.parse will likely get called before any `'data'` callbacks fire.

Comment: It's actually the 'end' event.

Answer (score 1):

"Unexpected end of input" is the error message you'll get from trying to parse an empty string or incomplete JSON string:

```
// examples
JSON.parse('')
JSON.parse('{')
```

So it sounds like your data source is unreliable. The proper way to handle this is to return a [400-range response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) to the client if/when the JSON.parse() step fails.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am sending message as shown in the question (I edited now) and showed you how I am trying to parser. looks I am missing some thing else

Answer (score 1):

```
function connectionHandler(request, response) {
    var data = '';

    request.on('data', function(buffer) {
        data += buffer;
    });

    request.on('end', function() {
        response.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });

        try {
            data = JSON.parse(data.toString());
        } catch (e) {
            response.end();
            return;
        }

        if (!data) {
            return;
        }

        // process "data" here
    })
}
```