# nodejs partial data just from firefox

Tags: node.js, firefox, formidable

I have a server running on nodejs, and I have the following piece of code to manage a post request -

```
form.on('file', function (field, file) {
   var RecordingInfo = JSON.parse(file.name);
...
```

when I tried to upload a file I got the following exception:

```
undefined:1
"}


SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at IncomingForm.<anonymous> (.../root.js:31:34)
...
```

[searching around the web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212956/node-js-and-json-runtime-error), I fond that this exception is caused because the data comes in bits, and the event is fired after the first bit arrives, and I don't have all the data. OK. The thing is, after a little testing I fond that from chrome I can upload large files (tried a 1.75gb file) without any problem, while firefox crashes the server with a 6kb file.

My question is - why are they different?

A sample capture can be downloaded form [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/91810930/http.pcapng). The first post is from chrome, the second from firefox.

The complete file.name string before uploading is:

```
// chrome
"{"subject":"flksajfd","lecturer":"אבישי וינר","path":"/גמרא","fileType":".png"}"
// firefox
"{"subject":"fdsa","lecturer":"אלקס ציקין","path":"/גמרא","fileType":".jpg"}"
```

(The data submitted is not the same, but I don't think it matters)

Comment: What's the diff between the input for FF and Chrome?

Comment: @Oleander I added a capture from wireshark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome is encoding double-quotes in the JSON-encoded "filename" as `%22` while Firefox is encoding them as `\"`.

Your file upload parsing library, [Formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable), explicitly [truncates the filename from the last `\` character](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/blob/master/lib/incoming_form.js#L430). It expects double-quotes to be encoded as `%22` although RFC 2616 allows backslash-escaped quotes like Firefox has implemented. You can consider this a bug in Formidable. The result is that the following JSON string:

```
'{"subject":"fdsa",...,"fileType":".jpg"}'
```

...is encoded as follows:

```
'{%22subject%22:%22fdsa",...,%22fileType%22:%22.jpg%22}' // Chrome
'{\"subject\":\"fdsa\",...\"fileType\":\".jpg\"}' // Firefox
```

...and then decoded by Formidable:

```
'{"subject":"fdsa",..."fileType":".jpg"}' // Chrome
'"}' // Firefox
```

To fix the issue you have a few choices:

1. [Raise the issue with Formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/issues/new) to correctly handle backslash-escaped quoted-value strings (or fix it yourself and submit a pull request).
2. Send the JSON payload in a separate part of the `FormData` object, e.g. [using a `Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects).
3. Transliterate all double-quote characters in your JSON-format filename to a 'safe' character that will not appear elsewhere in the string (I chose `^` as an example); replace the quote client-side and reinstate it server-side as follows.

Client:

```
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', $scope.recording, JSON.stringify(RecordingInfo).replace(/"/g, '^');
```

Server

```
form.on('file', function (field, file) {
   var RecordingInfo = JSON.parse(file.name.replace(/\^/g, '"');
```

Comment: doesn't seem to do the trick - running in nodejs `JSON.parse("{\"test\" : 3}")` yields `{test: 3}`, and not an error. Also, quite strangely, I get just the closing bracket, while according to your theory I should get the opening bracket.

Comment: I think the stringg has been mangled before it even reaches the `JSON.parse`. Did you try printing the string?

Comment: the same - FF: `name: "{"subject":"fdsa","lecturer"...` chrome: `name: "{"subject":"flksajfd","lecturer"...`

Comment: @elyashiv and do they both parse properly after printing them or does the FF one fail? Can you update the question with the complete strings?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce this - can you share the part of your client-side code that sends the file and/or point me to the client-side framework you are using?

Comment: you can see the whole code in [github](https://github.com/elyashiv/recordingSystem-yhe). The html file is in [here](https://github.com/elyashiv/recordingSystem-yhe/blob/master/public/html/index.html) and the code for uploading in [here](https://github.com/elyashiv/recordingSystem-yhe/blob/master/public/js/Controllers/recordingSystemCtrl.js#L42)